# Snap.svg — remove an object when one of the elements was clicked

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have an object with 3 elements bound in one group and I need to remove this object (or at least it's graphical representation — the group) when green rectangle is clicked.
The a.click() works, but c.click() doesn't and I'd like to know why:

```
var s = Snap(500, 500);

function myObj() {

    this.g = s.group();

    this.drawIt = function() {

    var a = s.rect(0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0).attr({'fill':'#E82941'}),
        b = s.rect(20, 20, 50, 50, 0, 0).attr({'fill':'#FF6E00'}),
        c = s.rect(40, 40, 50, 50, 0, 0).attr({'fill':'#00C049'});

        this.g.append(a, b, c);

        a.click(function(e){this.attr({'fill':'#000'});});
        c.click(this.killIt);
    }

    this.killIt = function() {
        this.g.remove();    
    }

}

var obj = new myObj();

obj.drawIt();
```

Snap.svg 0.3.0.

…

Solved: http://codepen.io/GeMir/pen/KwbBqV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the problem of closure, the `this` inside the `c.click` handler doesn't represent `myObj`.

Declare a variable `var that=this;` inside the constructor `myObj` like below

```
function myObj() {

  var that = this;

  this.g = s.group();

  this.drawIt = function() {
    var a = s.rect(0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0).attr({'fill':'#E82941'}),
        b = s.rect(20, 20, 50, 50, 0, 0).attr({'fill':'#FF6E00'}),
        c = s.rect(40, 40, 50, 50, 0, 0).attr({'fill':'#00C049'});

        this.g.append(a, b, c);

        a.click(function(e){this.attr({'fill':'#000'});});
        c.click(function(e){that.killIt()});
  }

  this.killIt = function() {
            this.g.remove();    
  }

}

var obj = new myObj();

obj.drawIt();
```

If you declare a function inside another function, the `this` variable will not be the same as that of parent function. in this case, it will be pointed to the `c`object, In the case of `a.click`, as the `this` is pointed to `a`, it worked.

Comment: Thank you! that.killIt() removes only "a" not the complete group. Is there a way to remove the group including "a", "b" and "c" shapes?

Comment: Coz, only `a` is present in the `g`, instead of `this.append(a,b,c)` try  `this.g.append(a); this.g.append(b);this.g.append(c);` . It worked.

Comment: Thank you! I never used append with multiple parameters before.

Comment: Out of interest would it also be valid to replace `this.killIt` with `() => {this.killIt()}` ?